# Why does my built typescript package expose classes I didn't export in my source code?

Tags: typescript, npm, es6-class, parceljs, type-declaration

Why does my built typescript package expose classes I didn't export in my source code?
I only exported classes that inherit these "Base classes", but they are still added to my built files and also declared in index.d.ts.I use parcel for bundling.

I export my classes like this in the source code,

```
export { Stack } from './ds/stack/Stack';
export { LimitedStack } from "./ds/stack/LimitedStack";
export { SinglyLinkedList } from "./ds/linked-lists/SinglyLinkedList";
export { DoublyLinkedList } from "./ds/linked-lists/DoublyLinkedList";
```

And I implemented these classes like,

```
Stack<T> extends BaseStack<T>
LimitedStack<T> extends BaseStack<T>
SinglyLinkedList<T> extends LinkedList<T>
DoublyLinkedList<T> extends LinkedList<T>
```

I thought that these base classes won't be available to users since I don't export them in my index.ts.But when I test my bundled package using yarn link
, I'm able to see Base Classes.
But when I try to create objects out of it, it throws an Error saying "Base.. is not a constructor", I can understand the reason. But my problem is why won't typescript give errors when I try to do,

```
const stack = new BaseStack() // This doesn't give a warning in the editor, but when trying to run it, it fails.
```

Why is this happening? Can I stop it? also tried using JS, It fails but there isn't a warning from the editor. I thought typescript would recognize this error.

Comment: `index.ts` is not for exporting. The re-export pattern is evil.

Comment: I'm pretty new to package building, this is what I saw from a few tutorials. I honestly don't know what else to do lol. Can you give me some idea?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer the original question (hence no answer from me), but my point is that if you're using `index.ts` or a similar file solely for re-exporting components / classes / types / enums / etc., that are originally defined in other files, then don't.

Comment: By saying this I suggest abandoning the re-export pattern, exporting/importing entities directly from the original definition files, and seeing if it helps (it probably will)

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky  ah,  I actually don't know how else to do it, I guess I'll try configuring multiple entry points in parcel. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky Yeah, I'll try